# ng-if'ed element gets rendered even though the condition's not fulfilled

Tags: html, linux, angular

I'm just starting at Angular.

I'm building a component; its footer and header should be visible only if these parameters are passed in.

panel.component.ts:

```
    export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() alignment = 'center';
  @Input() color = '';
  @Input() header = '';
  @Input() footer = '';
```

panel.component.html:

```
<!--Panel-->
<div class="card" style="width: 22rem;" [ngClass]="(alignment==='left')?'text-left':(alignment==='right')?'text-right':'text-center'">
  <div class="card-header {{color}} white-text" ng-if="!header===''">
  </div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted {{color}} white-text ng-if="!footer===''" ">
      <p class="mb-0">{{footer}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/.Panel-->
```

html:

```
    <panel color="success-color">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Special</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Check it out!</p>
    </div>
</panel>
```

The problem is, no matter what I pass in for `header` or `footer` in my html, they actually get rendered; not passing anything just makes the top and bottom `div`s empty, but existing.

What am I missing? Pls halp

Love, Paco

Comment: It should be `*ngIf ` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: <div class="card-footer text-muted {{color}} white-text ng-if="!footer===''" ">

Also here is some issue with (") this symbol

Comment: Using `*ngIf` indeed makes the footer and header disappear - the problem now is, no matter what I pass as footer/header arguments to <panel>, they just don't get rendered at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue is here :**

```
ng-if="!footer===''" "
```

**First Issue :**

use `*ngIf` not `ng-if`

**Second :**

`"!footer===''" "` should be `"footer!==''"` or `"!(footer==='')"`